# i have been trying to print a images ,where images is in another folder and the id of image is in another csv folder

Tags: python, image, visualization, detection

```
train_image = []
for i in tqdm(range(a.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img('C:\Users\Acer\Pictures\archive(1)\vinbigdata

\train'+a['image_id'][i]+'.png',target_size=(400,400,3))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    train_image.append(img)
X = np.array(train_image)
#this the code.  a is the csv file containing ids of image
and the error that i am getting is
 File "<ipython-input-37-556a7dc6abfa>", line 3
    img = image.load_img('C:\Users\Acer\Pictures\archive(1)\vinbigdata\train'+a['image_id'][i]+'.png',target_size=(400,400,3))
                        ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Pictures\\archive(1)\\vinbigdata

\\train'+a['image_id'][i]+'.png',target_size=(400,400,3))
```

Add one more `\` in your path

or
add an `r` to make a raw string

```
r'C:\Users\Acer\Pictures\archive(1)\vinbigdata

\train'+a['image_id'][i]+'.png'
```

> \Uxxxxxxxx  Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx
> You've 'C:\Users .Python treats it as an escape character